# Cookie not getting saved in browser but works fine with postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, next.js

ok so everything was working fine when the backend and the front end where hosted in Localhost

but when i deployed the backend to **(Heroku)** and the frontend to **(Vercel)** both **HTTPS**
and set the cookie to sameSite="NONE" secure, the browser does not set the cookie anymore, but postman works just fine, i tried to many CORS options nothing works

// **both backend and frontend have Credentials included** //

here's the backend express CORS config

```
///////////// Express cors config ///////////
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: true,
        credentials: true,
        exposedHeaders: ['Set-Cookie'],
        allowedHeaders: [
            'Authorization',
            'Content-Type',
            'membership-id',
            'account-id',
            'X-Requested-With',
            'Accept',
            'Origin',
        ],
    }),
);
```

cookie

```
const token = jwt.sign({userID: user._id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: 900,
});
res.setHeader(
    'Set-Cookie', cookie.serialize('token', token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'none',
        secure: true,
        maxAge: 900,
        path: '/',
    }),
);
```

and frontend with axios

```
const API = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://apiplalapalpl.com',
    withCredentials: true,
  });

const res = await API.post('/api/user/login', { email, password });
```

here's some pictures from chrome

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvc7X.png ,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/57jH4.png

please help, i'm about to pull my HAIR out :(

Comment: The images you posted show a successful request to the `/login` endpoint with the cookie set in both the request and the response headers, and it also shows the cookie being present in the browser. Am I missing something or doesn't that mean it's working?

Comment: it does not show up in the Cookie Storage!

Comment: Hey, did you solve this issue?